# Problema com Feign Client

Tags: java, spring-boot

Boa tarde estou com um pequeno problema em me conectar em outra API com o feign client, o que acontece que testando localmente funciona, quando subo para a produção que ele simplesmente da um notfound.

Codigo do Feign CLient Service

```
@FeignClient("service-buscar-indice")

public interface BuscarIndiceFinanceiroService {
public static final String HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION= "Authorization";
static final String HTTP_HEADER_APPLICATION = "Application";

@GetMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String buscarIndice(
        @RequestHeader(name = HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) String authorizationHeaderValue,
        @RequestHeader(name = HTTP_HEADER_APPLICATION) String application,
        @RequestParam(name = "codigo", required = true) String codigo);

}
```

Codigo da controller da outra api (sim o feign já está enable e etc... localmente funciona, esse é o problema kk)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "")
public class BuscarIndiceController {

@Autowired
private BuscarIndiceService buscarIndiceService;

@GetMapping(path="")
public String buscarIndiceFinanceiro(@RequestParam(name="codigo",required=true) String codigo){
    return buscarIndiceService.buscarIndicePorCodigo(codigo);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

O @FeignClient ainda não suporta as anotações @GetMapping,  @PostMapping, @UpdateMapping e @DeleteMapping, utilize @RequestMapping no lugar do @GetMapping.